# How to parametrise vardef declarations for suffixed variables with tags?

Tags: metapost, metafont

In metapost, I'm trying to define a macro which provides declarations for various related properties.

I have an "object" (xyz in this example) which I'm representing by a suffix on a variable, and several properties of the object, which I'm representing by tags on that suffix, `.a`, `.b`, `.c` etc.

My goal is to have these variables declared by my macro, rather than the caller declaring them.

I have:

```
vardef S@#(expr p) =
    pair s@#.a;
    pair s@#.b;
    pair s@#.c;

    s@#.c := p;
    draw s@#.c withpen pencircle scaled 6bp withcolor blue;
enddef;

beginfig(1)
    S.abc(origin);
    S.xyz(origin);
endfig;

end.
```

This is fine for naming my "objects" `abc` and `xyz`, but I would like them to be named numerically, as if they were an array, such that I might write:

```
S0(origin);
S1(origin);
```

I don't understand why this is an error, because as far as I understand it ought to produce a variable `s0.c`. But:

```
! Illegal suffix of declared variable will be flushed.
<to be read again>
                   1
S->begingroup.pair.s(SUFFIX2)
                             c;
```

Is it possible to do this?

I wouldn't mind slightly alternate syntax, something like `n(S0, origin)` if that's neccessary. But I'm trying to take advantage of Metapost's suffixes (either explicitly or implicitly) in combination with tags.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you can't have an explicit subscript in a declaration.

When `@#` is expanded to a numeric token, such as `0`, your macro tries to declare `pair s0a;` which triggers the error you see.

Metapost syntax rules only allow "collective" subscripts in type declarations.  These are represented by empty brackets `[]`, so if you want to use numbers for the objects, you have to change the declarations to:

```
pair s[]a;
pair s[]b;
pair s[]c;
```

But this will *only* work with numbers, so you will be able to have

```
S0(origin);
```

but not

```
S.abc(origin); % <-- won't work
```

### A bit of background

It might help to review the rules about tokens. Metapost follows the tokenizing rules set out in Chapter 6 of Knuth's Metafont Book.  There are three types of tokens:

- Numeric tokens, like `3.14`, `42`, `.866`
- String tokens, like `"phvr8r"` that start and end with `"`
- Symbolic tokens (everything else).

Symbolic tokens are then divided into "sparks" and "tags": a "spark" is symbolic token that means something to MP (either the name of a primitive command or of a defined macro); every other symbolic token is a tag.

When you declare a new variable, it's name must start with a tag.

This rule sounds arcane, but it simply means that you can't have variable names that start with a string, or with a numeric token, or with a name that's already been used for a macro or a primitive command.
This is pretty normal for a programming language.

The tricky bit of variable names in MP is that you are also allowed to add a thing called a "suffix" to the name.  The rules for a valid suffix say that it is either

- empty
- or a valid suffix followed by a tag
- or a valid suffix followed by a thing called a "subscript", which is either a simple numeric token or an expression enclosed in brackets that evaluates to a numeric value.

This means you can have variable names like `p.a` or `s12` or `k43left`, `t[42]` or `f[i+1]`.  The ones with brackets look a lot like arrays, but they are not really.

The only restriction is that variables with subscripts must all have the same type.  This is enforced by the rule noted above that forbids explicit subscripts in type declarations, but allows "collective" subscripts.

### Possible solution

If you want a find a fully generic way of declaring related properties, then you could reuse the `generic_declare` routines from the standard `boxes.mp` file, which will be in your local texmf tree.