# METAPOST syntax to set all values of an array at once

Tags: metapost

I would like to set all values of a METAPOST array in a single line
as I would write in other programming langages.

In all of the examples I could find, or the manuals example,  one defines array elements individually, wich I find very tedious if the array is long :

```
pair B[];
B1 :=(5,60);
B2 := ...
etc...
```

Among others I tried the following, but all produces errors :

```
B[] := ((5,60),(5,-115),(10,180));
B := (5,60),(5,-115),(10,180);
B := [(5,60),(5,-115),(10,180)];
....
```

Is there synthetic way to set the values of large array?
I can't find any reference, it might not even be possible in metapost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array-like naming convention `B[1]`, `E[3]` is a MetaPost construction with so-called subscripts (in our case, `1` and `3`) rather than real arrays, which MetaPost doesn't handle with. But, as a macro language, you could define your own macro to automatically create pairs (please correct me if I'm using the wrong terminology):

```
vardef ListofPairs(suffix $)(text Pairs) =
    save i_; i_ := 0; %save makes i_ local
    pair $[]; %define a pair with the variable name $
    %Typical loop over passed elements
    for i = Pairs: $[i_] := i; i_ := i_ + 1; endfor;
enddef;

ListofPairs(B)((5,60),(5,-115),(10,180));

drawdot B[0] withpen pensquare scaled 12 withcolor red;
drawdot B[1] withpen pencircle scaled 10 withcolor green;
drawdot B[2] withpen pencircle scaled 8 withcolor blue;
```

[image]

As a friendly recommendation, don't expect MetaPost to be like "normal" programming languages. Instead, the [MetaPost manual](https://www.tug.org/docs/metapost/mpman.pdf) is a good starting point (`texdoc metapost` if you have a complete distribution installed). *The METAFONTBook* is recommended too, but tbh I didn't read it so far.

Comment: I understand, this is a nice workaround. Thanx, I will use it. Could you explain what means 'suffix'?

Comment: @msarch You could use `expr`, `text` or `suffix`. You use `suffix` when you work with variable names. [Here a brief explanation of the curious naming convention in Metapost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298318/how-to-parametrise-vardef-declarations-for-suffixed-variables-with-tags/298501#298501).

Comment: @msarch I made a small correction with `vardef` instead of `def`. The former keeps definitions declared with `save` local, while the latter doesn't. Sorry

Answer (score 2):

This answer is really not much more than a comment on the other one, but the comment box is too small.  There are a couple of useful built-in features and macros in `plain.mp` that help with this sort of task in Metapost.

Consider the following little program:

```
vardef makePairs@#(text arguments) =
    save i; numeric i; i = -1;
    pair @#[];
    for t = arguments: 
        @#[incr i] = t; 
    endfor;
enddef;

makePairs B ((0,1), (1, 2), (2, 3));

for i=0 upto 9:
    if known B[i]: show i; show B[i]; fi
endfor
end
```

If you run this with `mpost` you should get the following output

```
>> 0
>> (0,1)
>> 1
>> (1,2)
>> 2
>> (2,3)
```

### Notes

- I've avoided using the trailing `_` in my variable names, to avoid any possibility of overwriting something in `plain.mp`, where `_` is used in the names of internal variables
- I have used the special suffix parameter notation `@#` instead of a delimited `suffix` parameter.  This allows for a slightly more "natural" syntax; the user can write `makePairs B ((0,1),....)` instead of `makePairs(B)((0,1),...)`.
- After `save i`, I have redeclared `i` as numeric, so that any previous value is removed. This is just good practice.
- I have used the macro `incr` from `plain.mp` to increment the index instead of the clunky `i := i + 1` syntax.
- Finally I have used `known` to check whether a particular suffix is defined in my "array".  In Metapost, variables with numeric suffixes are quite unlike arrays in other languages, despite appearances. So it is possible to define `B[0]` and `B[2]`, without defining `B[1]` and there is no way to check the "length" of suffixed variable.

### Further simplification

And if you like the above, note that you can omit the parentheses from the final parameter, so we can make the syntax even less fussy for the user, like this:

```
vardef declarePairs@# text arguments =
    save i; numeric i; i = -1;
    pair @#[];
    for t = arguments: 
        @#[incr i] = t; 
    endfor;
enddef;

declarePairs B (0,1), (1, 2), (2, 3);

for i=0 upto 9:
    if known B[i]: show i; show B[i]; fi
endfor
end
```

### And yet another idea

Depending on what you want to do with all the pairs in the "array", one other possibility is to create them all as a single `path`:

```
path p; 
p = (0,1) .. (1,2) .. (2,3);
```

then you can get at each pair with `point 0 of p`, `point 1 of p`, and so on.  You don't actually have to draw the path, you could just use it as a sort-of list structure.  And in this case MP *does* provide a `length` command and you can reverse it with `reversed` or do certain simple bits of arithmetic on the whole thing. For example `p := p shifted up` would add 1 to the `ypart` of each point in the path.

Comment: I can remove my answer if it is so ill-written. I was aware of the `known` check, but I think it's up to the user to rewrite or append content to an "array"...

Comment: @JairoA.delRio please don't be offended! I have not said there was anything "wrong" with your answer, I was just trying to point out some useful features of the language that are relevant to the question.  I could have edited my ideas into your answer (since it has the tick) but I thought that would be  too arrogant.

Comment: Definitely not sarcastic, just trying to be helpful...